# How to update the type of a property on a class instance?

Tags: typescript

I am making a builder class that has a property, `store`, which is essentially a Record that is continuously modified each time `addEntry` is called. The returned type works.

However, the update to `store` on the original instance doesn't get updated. What do I do?

```js
type plugin = {
  name:string,
  createEntry(...params:any[]):any
}
type PluginMap<T extends ReadonlyArray<plugin>> = {
  [key in T[number] as key["name"]]: key["createEntry"] extends ((...args:any[])=>any)? key["createEntry"]:never
}

type storeEntry<K extends PropertyKey,T extends (...args:any)=>any>={
  store:{
    [key in K]:ReturnType<T>
  }
}

type UsingPluginMap<T extends ReadonlyArray<plugin>, Key extends T[number]["name"]>=PluginMap<T>[Key]

class BuilderUsingPlugins<T extends ReadonlyArray<plugin>> {
  store = { }
  plugins: PluginMap<T>
  addEntry<P extends T[number]["name"],K extends PropertyKey>(
    pluginValueType: P,
    name: K,
    ...pluginParams: Parameters<UsingPluginMap<T,P>>
  ): this & storeEntry<K,UsingPluginMap<T,P>> {
    
    this.assignAndAssert< typeof this["store"],K,ReturnType<UsingPluginMap<T,P>>>(this["store"],name,this.plugins[pluginValueType](pluginParams))

    this.assignAndAssert<this, "store",typeof this["store"]>(this,"store",this["store"]) 
    return this as this & storeEntry<K,UsingPluginMap<T,P>>
  }
  private assignAndAssert<T extends object,K extends PropertyKey,V>(t:T,k:K,v:V): asserts t is T &{[key in K]:V}{
    Object.assign(t,{[k]:v})
  }

  constructor(params:T){
    this.plugins = params.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
      return {
        ...acc,
        ...{[curr.name]:curr.createEntry} as const satisfies PluginMap<[typeof curr]>
      }
    },{} ) as PluginMap<typeof params>
  }

}
const fooPlugin={
  createEntry(){
    return 'I am the "foo" plugin!'
  },
  name:"foo"
} as const satisfies plugin

const barPlugin = {
  name:"bar",
  createEntry(someparam:number):number{
    return someparam
  }
} as const satisfies plugin

const bazPlugin = {
  name:"baz",
  createEntry(enumishArg:["hello","world"][number]):["hello","world"][number]{
    return enumishArg
  }
} as const satisfies plugin
const bastoPlugin = {
  name:"basto",
  createEntry(enump:ReadonlyArray<string>):typeof enump{
    return enump as typeof enump
  }
} as const satisfies plugin
const MyPluginList = [fooPlugin,barPlugin,bazPlugin,bastoPlugin] as const 
const builder = new BuilderUsingPlugins<typeof MyPluginList>(MyPluginList)

//  Mwa-hahahaha!! It works! 
builder.addEntry("foo","fooEntry").store //  {} & { fooEntry: string;}
//  No! Wait! 
builder.store // {} ?
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGA2CuBzAlgOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALgGdgAnNRAGnygGMaIjgIBRVWkABQA6EWCI1SlckVQgA2gF0AlNNm4AvrlCQoABQQpUAWSJgAPABUoEAB5dUAE0pQAShwcB7VLBABBGhIgZnBIaAB8YZg4zHIA1hAgUGhQFnKo8CQARhA0ClBEzvHyAETEZMUKCuRQRXLFbBxcvPwV1nYQjs4CwiLiiFIy8soYYYNKAPw1CXUNnDx8NCAV5KgQAG45Grha4NDUHuzNi2YA0m32Tno0HpA0oCcJDFa2F10iQn0Dskojg2EYeAI+3Y5EBBCgcQSSXQJyqbmA8BoqAsu0sYWYmk0Ox0AFVKPR9KFjKZLOcOpc3ERPN4-AEiEEQoYwgwoA9Ei9yc5UuksjkFHUyhAKv9CYYTOYLGE5GyFNsWLACs4AELwZCwBw5PEEgxoSikjmdVzuLw+fyBYI61ARaJA4AHaBYbBQTQERm66qitDitHMKkOI5BXRkw3cjLZXIC0hChQMM4Gy66a63e4JMICZiuy0ANSICAgKMgHqY4MIUeqJ2L4PebtQunEkg99bIXBoeq1qEQnuJEoYugizBUUGAAAtkM4AGRQYHzfinBjtzuW70WXvWsEEDND0eUD6UfGIVC+Ry+Pc5YBmIe7DwAMy3Y7q04qsYY8MRyNRC67y9XEQEI-vxSPjGgoMP+O41pQcg1jmeYFhACgCDWdYSCQlBKEo2wlmBu77oex6nncZhgSygF2uwxSgVet5gQ+ZHRmmxGkfaFE0Ux5HKFAm7sAiSJ3s4BR8VAk7TgGc6fkuJIrn26IEC6MB0Gscz5HuyAHkeDgnpQZ76u0hoeJkABWEAsMAsbBgmSZniAbIMFmDHkCusTkBWazkFmg6KmezjAEkXJCdgkKJMksJueo65QAA8oZxnADhqmoH+DABbEVRrOoGGyZhrBeNQNDwCZByIU2UgWEo4XYRBURiChO7sA4+UQN0RAsCwDAsIiNA-GE4UENxb42iWVa9C1laDVA7wBe1ARCIKVRTTQQizE0CwgOoynZag1BTpwY7XsgEDOF+JJyNoEA3qwHUKDJg1ybJSVrUo61HeYp3ndVkjXVimgsDlPnXh4HhdgCzBLTOiwCGVXEQDx6AAOQAJL5CQW7QMU-0eMUMCWgAhLDGKVoK5BowDxQaOtP2bT5lA7ZQe0HVjRJyr9UCZOIXZRGChPFKzNAUSD7BzAGAiUB4ZDvSQKxhjkKg8uG4V9bxIti02GJkwJFNbdTwC7ftzg1kzlMs0QABe7OOswXOs8bfMEKDQsdBkY7Dv4iDkHUw4QLAsAYwwxQAO4HOqFRpFLuQqO7nvexR-uBw4wey3y8vQ-1DskE7Luq2t6vM1rOv0-rGs+az+xmwNlsFHaNusALy38AIqdgOQlLUqadJBLl9BhCor23g3Scw9YPJgOtPeDxkYCZ+TOc03TeuWrghdQEYIBdgAMmOPlYHI6NdgwPO71bB8V4Dlp5NnhsL8zmSquqORRKsftQCqaoajQ4lEnqo-L2vG9pt-lrr2oBhXAAB6EBBAjB+yIAAWmHEQOBCCiDY2xlAeGPkA40FiJQFBuBr4vxyB8Bw-oVoCGJj7MhAZihKCENOKAYCCDYDWpOJ06MAzVA7h2AA3JoehUAAByHgUEAHUiDIGADgvBt8Fq0PoYwqA4xcBAA)

Comment: This code is quite long and your problem description isn't clear enough for me to understand (there seem to be verbs missing from your sentences).  Could you [edit] to clarify the English and make sure the code is a [mre]?

Comment: I *think* from reading this that what you want is not possible; there is at least one open feature request for this, see [ms/TS#40562](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40562).  Is that the feature you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining.